# How to pass onPress in a map function to a custom component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a `icons.js` which consist of an array of objects:

```
const icons =[
  { name: 'Camera', image: <Icon name='device-camera' size={70}  />, onPress: pickSingleWithCamera},
  { name: 'Earth', image: <SimpleLineIcons name='camera'  size={70} />, onPress: 'bye' }
]
```

`picksinglWithCamera` is a function:

```
const pickSingleWithCamera = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: true,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: {uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height},
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }
```

Now I have the main component in `main.js` which imports both the `icons.js` and `title.js` files.

The title component:

```
<Title
  text={ focused ? focused.name : '' }
  data={this.cells}
  top={(SIZE + GUTTER) * 2}
  visibility={this.text}
/>
```

What I am trying to do here is whenever user presses the text (name attribute of array icons), the respective function of it is called.

Unfortunately I am unsuccessful doing that, that's why I came onto SO to ask.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Animated, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert, View } from 'react-native'
import { HIDDEN, VISIBLE } from './animation-state'

export default class Title extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {}
  }

  action(text, top, visibility, data) {
    return data.map((cell, i) => {
      return (
        <Animated.View
        key={i}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            opacity: visibility.interpolate({
              inputRange: [HIDDEN, VISIBLE],
              outputRange: [0, 1],
            }),
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            transform: [
              {
                translateY: visibility.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [HIDDEN, VISIBLE],
                  outputRange: [100, 0],
                }),
              },
            ],
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => cell.onPress}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 40,
                fontFamily: 'GillSans-SemiBold',
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}
            >
              {text}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { text, top, visibility, data } = this.props
    return (
      <View>
        {this.action(text, top, visibility, data)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `onPress: 'bye'` supposed to do, and where does `cells` come from. did you mean icons?

Comment: @azium haha , sry for that , consider 'bye' as a func only as pickSinglWithcamera is . Yes cells are icons consisiting of two objects defined in icons.

Comment: well it looks like your problem is not calling your function. either change to `onPress={cell.onPress}` or `onPress={() => cell.onPress()}`

Comment: @azium yes awesome! you're right, but the other issue is its always taking last object :(

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions have immediate returns, in your case what you are doing translates to the following:

```
onPress={function(){return cell.onPress;}}
```

This will do nothing because you are not executing the function, you have to tell the function to execute

```
onPress={() => cell.onPress()}
```

Another solution would be to just assign the function without arrow functions, this has the downside that `onPress` won't be binded to the component

```
onPress={cell.onPress}
```